# How to keep clicked button highlighted in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my windows vb.net form thre are 3 buttons. those are button1,button2 button3.
i need to keep clicked button highlighted until another one clicked. i used some code but unsucsessful.what is the wrong with me?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Button2.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Button3.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Button3.BackColor = Color.SteelBlue
    Button2.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub
```

i need to keep clicked button highlighted in steel blue colour until another one clicked.unclicked buttons must be in transparent backcolour.

Comment: You could potentially use `RadioButton` controls instead. If you set the `Appearance` property to `Button` then the controls will look like regular `Buttons` but clicking one will depress it and leave it depressed until you click a different one in the same set. They work exactly the same way as regular `RadioButtons` but look like `Buttons`. You can then just handle the `CheckedChanged` events and test that the `Checked` property is `True`.

Comment: Your method working wery well for me.Thanks in advance & appriciate.